# Reference to equations doesn't work including hyperref

Tags: equations, hyperref, labels

I'm having some problems with the reference of equations. In particular they don't work properly when I include the package `hyperref`.

If I do:

```
\begin{equation}\label{einstein}
E=m^{2}
\end{equation}
```

and then I try to reference it as

```
\ref{einstein}
```

The name of the label (einstein) is printed instead of the number of the equation, and also the following writing is affected in a weird way.

I think it may be that I'm creating some package conflicts in my preamble, which is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase Chapter \arabic{chapter}}

% Useful packages
\usepackage{empheq,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbold}

\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{float}    
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-    \arraycolsep}}
\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}


\title{Notes \\
{\Large University}}
\author{Me}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter*{Abstract}

\include{introduction}

\include{chap1}

\include{conclusion}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: where is the `\begin{document}... \end{document` ?

Comment: don't show only snippets, show a small but complete example, (remove irrelevant packages).

Comment: Also, `subcaption` and `subfigure` are exclusive towards each other. `Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package.`

Comment: You are asked to provide a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: That example is not minimal and refers to files we do not have access to. Make sure your example is self contained such that others can copy and test it as is. Also make it minimal by removing stuff that are not related to your problem.

Comment: Additionally what is that `.` doing in the `geometry line?

Comment: If I replace the body of your MWE by the equation given and the `\ref` plus removed the subfig/caption already mentioned, plus removes that `.` on the geometry line, then the example compiles just fine and the hyperlink works just fine.

Comment: I have my doubts that your document compiles without error at our end. Please don't ignore compilation errors even if a PDF is produced. The PDF are likely to contain accumulative errors.

Comment: @daleif Indeed the pdf is generated by there is the error about the conflicting sub caption and subfigure. I'm now try to provide MWE as requested.

Comment: Aside: Noting good *ever* comes from loading packages more than once (cf `mathtools`), loading obsolete packages (`subfigure`) that conflict openly with other, more modern packages (such as `subcaption`), running redundant code (e.g., why do you execute `\addbibresource{sample.bib}` *twice*?), or not addressing error messages (such as what you *must* be getting because of the extraneous `.` character in the `\usepackagep[...].{geometry}` line). Please do yourself a major favor and eliminate these issues from your preamble.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint! If I follow your advice the problem seems to be solve. However what do you mean  I'm executing **\addbibresource{sample.bib}** twice?The character **.** in the geometric package was an error that came while pasting the code here.

Comment: You ask, "what do you mean I'm executing `\addbibresource{sample.bib}` twice?" Well, there are two instances of `\addbibresource{sample.bib}`, aren't there?

Comment: @Mico oh yes you are right, I didn't see it. thanks!

Comment: @Matteo: Can you please review this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) and update your example code accordingly? You're using `\include` and we don't have the accompanying files. Also, there's probably no need for including your bibliographic stuff (like `\addbibresource`), is there?

Comment: You loaded the `cleveref` package but did not use its `\cref` macro. So it seems there is no need to load that package.